# <ion-router-outlet> is not working in Ionic 4

Tags: angular-routing, ionic4

I am trying to add two child pages in parent page with two tabs in Ionic 4 using below code, but I was confused about `<ion-router-outlet>` not showing admin with two tabs. When I select tabs respective pages have to show but it's directly showing child1 page.

I was wondering when I use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` it's working fine. What did I do wrong?

### admin.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-4><button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="child1()">Child1</button></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4><button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="child2()">Child2</button></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>

</ion-content>
```

### admin-router.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'Admin',
        component: AdminPage,
        children: [
            { path: '',redirectTo: '/Admin/Child1',pathMatch: 'full'},
            { path: 'Child1', component: Child1Page },
            { path: 'Child2', component: Child2Page },
        ]
    }
];
```

### adminModule.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
        AdminRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AdminPage,
        Child1Page,
        Child2Page
    ]
})
export class AdminModule {

}
```

Comment: Please share output of `ionic info` command

Answer (score 2):

Try to use angular `router-outlet` instead of `ion-router-outlet`

Comment: That worked for me; I was using ion-router-outlet with id to differentiate ion-router-outlets, which was working on web, but not in the android simulator.